# How do I label an image using the first two letters of a file name in an array?

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm in an introductory neural networking class so mind my ignorance.

I have a folder containing roughly 12,000 texture images, each divided into ten different subsets. An example file name would be *bubbly_0012.png*. Some file names begin with the same first letter, for example, *bubbly_0012.png* and *blotchy_0012.png*.

I'm trying to create a .csv file containing arrays of each of the images. I want to label each image according to their subset (and therefore their name), so that *bubbly* is given the label 0, *blotched* is given the label 1, as so on.

I found that I'm able to do this with the first letter of each file name using this line:

```
if (file[0]) == "b":
     name_array = [[0]]
```

However, this becomes an issue when I try and label subsets that begin with the same letter For the *blotchy* subset, I tried the following:

```
if (file[0:1]) == "bl":
     name_array = [[0]]
```

But this didn't work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you know all labels in advance, using a dictionary of string label to class would be the trivial solution

Comment: You want to group image file names? Do you want to group by the first letter of the file name or by the first word of the file? (i.e. bubbly_0001, bubbly_0002 and bubbly_0003 grouped together and blotchy_0001, blotchy_0002, blotchy_0003 grouped together)

Comment: For more information on slicing strings/lists/etc, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/7675174).

Answer (score 0):

Well in slices/ranges etc... the first index is `inclusive` while the second is not. So a slice of `[0:1]` will return the first index. to slice including the second digit we need to use `[0:2]` which will return the 0th  and 1th index. However if we already know the `keywords` it is best to use some other means.

```
my_dict_of_files_and_indexes = {"blotchy":1, "bubly":0} 
#if we manually fill out the fields then we can just use a list and index it

my_list_of_file_names = ["bubly", "blotchy"]

#for our list where its already in the correct order
if file in my_list_of_file_names:
    index_of_file = my_list_of_file_names.index(file)
    #do stuff with the file and index

#for our dict where the order of indexes don't matter
if my_dict_of_files_and_indexes.contains(file):
    index = my_dict_of_files_and_indexes[file]
    #do stuff with the file and index
```